# Removing conflicts of LR(1) parsing tables

Tags: parsers, lr-k

```
S' -> S $

S -> I ; S
S -> return E ; S
S -> return I ; S
S -> ''

I -> id
I -> id = E
I -> id = I

E -> C && C
E -> C || C
E -> ! C
E -> C

C -> A > A
C -> A < A
C -> A >= A
C -> A <= A
C -> A == A
C -> A

A -> T A'
A'-> + T A'
A'-> - T A'
A'->''

T -> F T'
T'-> * F T'
T'-> / F T'
T'->''

F -> id
F -> const
F -> ( A )
```

This is supposed to be a LR(1) grammar, but its LR(1) parsing table have a conflict on the `;` symbol column: it has both a shift and a reduction transition. How this conflict can be removed?

Comment: If it is supposed to be an LR grammar, why have you chosen to deform it to remove left-recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ambiguity comes from

```
I -> id
```

because that rule means that both `I` ans `E` derive `id`, which in turn means that `return id` could be a derivation of either:

```
S -> return E ; S
```

or

```
S -> return I ; S
```

Also, `id1 = id2` could be derived from:

```
I -> id = E
```

or

```
I -> id = I
```

It doesn't make sense for `id` to be a statement if `id + 3` is not; I'd just drop the `I -> id` production.